# In App Bar with buttons material-ui / core ': v3.9.1 cropping backgroundImage

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In App Bar with buttons material-ui / core ': v3.9.1 cropping backgroundImage.
[image]

In App Bar with buttons material-ui / core ': v3.0.3 everything worked well

[image]

Why? What can be scratched to work as in v3.0.3.
My code:

//https://material-ui.com/api/app-bar/ (App Bar with buttons)

```
    import React from "react";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
    import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
    import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
    import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
    import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";

    import logoRa from "../assets/images/all/SunRa48.png";

    const styles = {
      root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
      },
      grow: {
        flexGrow: 1,
      },
      menuButton: {
        marginLeft: -12,
        marginRight: 20,
      },
      logo: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${logoRa})`,
        backgroundSize: 45,
        backgroundPosition: "2px 2px",
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        borderRadius: "0%",
        marginRight: 10,
      },
    };

    function ButtonAppBar(props) {
      const { classes } = props;
      return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <AppBar position="static">
            <Toolbar>
              <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <IconButton className={classes.logo} component={Link} to="/aboutme" title="AboutMe" aria-label="logo" />
              <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" className={classes.grow}>
                News
              </Typography>
              <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
        </div>
      );
    }

    ButtonAppBar.propTypes = {
      classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };
export default withStyles(styles)(ButtonAppBar);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include a CodeSandbox that reproduces this.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Here is the code on CodeSandbox. But it does not work well with the latest version of Material-UI
https://codesandbox.io/s/kxp3n93k5  Something I can not install on CodeSandbox Material-UI v3.0.3. to show that it works correctly on this version

Answer (score 0):

Prior to version 3.1.0, `IconButton` had an explicit width and height of 48px.

In version 3.1.0, these were removed in order to support more flexible sizing of `IconButton`. Since you are doing your logo as a background image, the size collapsed down.

You can recover the old behavior by adding the width and height into your logo class:

```
  logo: {
    backgroundImage: `url(${logoRa})`,
    backgroundSize: 45,
    backgroundPosition: "2px 2px",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    borderRadius: "0%",
    marginRight: 10,
    width: 48, // added
    height: 48 // added
  }
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: Thank you very much. Something has not tried these properties

Comment: If this solved your problem. Please "accept" the answer. If you are unsure how to do that you can find instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).